# JDBC stored procedure call

Tags: java, mysql, java-stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure as follows:

//Stored procedures in mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `bank`.`hello` (in id varchar(20),in pass varchar(20))
BEGIN
 insert into admin(username,password) values (id,pass);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

and I am calling the stored procedure in java as follows:

//calling stored procedures using JDBC

```
package StoredProcEx;
import java.sql.*;
public class StoredProcEx {
    public static void main(String arg[]){
    try{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank","root","root");
    //PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into admin values(?,?)");
    CallableStatement stmt=con.prepareCall("{?=call hello(?,?)}");
    stmt.setString(1,"birender");
    stmt.setString(2,"admin");
    stmt.execute();
    //stmt.execute();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ce){
    ce.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SQLException se){
     se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

But it is showing a compile time exception as follows:

Can's set IN parameter for return value of stored function call.

Comment: what is your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Please use

```
CallableStatement stmt=con.prepareCall("{call hello(?,?)}");
```

instead of

```
CallableStatement stmt=con.prepareCall("{?=call hello(?,?)}");
```

First ? in your code is used for return type