# Call stored procedure in java

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, plsql

```
create or replace PROCEDURE employee_project1 (
  emp_id   in  EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE,
  cur      out SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN cur FOR
    SELECT p.project_id,
           p.project_name
    FROM   employees e
           INNER JOIN departments d
           ON ( e.department_id = d.department_id )
           INNER JOIN projects p
           ON ( p.department_id = e.department_id)
    WHERE  e.employee_id = emp_id;
END;
```

I have the above procedure. I execute the procedure with below code:

```
declare
    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    pro_id int;
    pro_name projects.project_name%TYPE;
begin
    employee_project1(43, cur);
    loop
        fetch cur into pro_id, pro_name;
        exit when cur%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(pro_id||' '||pro_name);
    end loop;
end;
```

I have to execute the procedure in java JDBC. So how to call the procedure in java with above execution code?

Comment: I've never used it, but Java has a [`CallableStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) class that you create from one of a `Connection` object's [`prepareCall`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall(java.lang.String)) methods.

Comment: It seems to be duplicating [JDBC stored procedure call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249130/jdbc-stored-procedure-call)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JDBC stored procedure call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249130/jdbc-stored-procedure-call)